# Displaying a box in Assembly Language 8086

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, ascii-art

I had a hard time figuring out how to create a box like in the picture below (expected result).
I also had some text inside the box. How would I be able to do it?

Please see the code, current result and the expected result below.

> CODE

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
    OUTPUT_HORIZONTAL_LINE DB 10, 13, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, "$" 
    OUTPUT_GENDER DB 10, 13, "Gender: Male$"
    OUTPUT_CIVIL DB 10, 13, "Civil status: Single$"
    OUTPUT_CHARACTER DB 10, 13, "Character: Neutral$" 
.CODE
    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX

    LEA DX, OUTPUT_HORIZONTAL_LINE
    MOV AH, 09H
    INT 21H

    LEA DX, OUTPUT_GENDER
    MOV AH, 09H
    INT 21H  

    LEA DX, OUTPUT_CIVIL
    MOV AH, 09H
    INT 21H   

    LEA DX, OUTPUT_CHARACTER
    MOV AH, 09H
    INT 21H

    LEA DX, OUTPUT_HORIZONTAL_LINE
    MOV AH, 09H
    INT 21H      

    MOV AH, 4CH
    INT 21H
END
```

**CURRENT RESULT**

[image: current result]

**EXPECTED RESULT (It should still have the text (gender, civil status, character))**

[image]

Comment: You don't really state a problem in your question. You'll have a more pleasant and flexible time if you write routines that help you draw lines, instead of simply writing out a fixed string of characters. If you want to have a a scrolling window, you'll probably have to write some graphics helper functions that are independent of the content you want to display. That's the hard part. From there, printing the data you want to show in the box would be trivial (because you've already done the hard work).

Comment: @ThomasJager. Sorry i just started learning assembly language. Not necessary a scrolling window for now. Just a static UI for now.

Comment: Either way, there are two ways of doing things. You can make things completely inflexible, and output certain strings at certain points to give the appearance you want. The better way would be to create those UI routines I mentioned in my first comment. You don't have to do anything fancy like scrolling, but being able to construct a UI is a good step. This is however a lot of work.